# error sintaxis al configurar Google Script con la database Realtime de Firebase

Tags: firebase, script, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy construyendo un script apartir de un tutorial en youtube [link tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdRLezi88fw&t=15s) agregue antes la libreria de FirebaseApp a GScript [que se encuentra aqui](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) luego seguí los pasos con el fin de enviar la información de mi database de firebase hacia una hoja de calculo o GSheet

**Código**:

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpredsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,4,2);  
  var data = getFirebaseData("actividades");
  Logger.log(data)
  range.setValue(JSON.parse(data))

}

function getFirebaseData(data){
  var firebaseUrl = "url_firebase";
  var secret = "clave";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
  var result = base.getData(data);
  return result;
}
```

Estoy obteniendo error al convertir el objeto JSON pero no encuentro como solucionarlo, agradezco cualquier info o recomendación al respecto!

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: o (línea 7, archivo "Código")
```

Agrego JSON:

```
 {
      "actividades" : {
        "-LkedSS_hu8wFohzt5aN" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "26/7/2019",
          "idKey" : "-LkedSS_hu8wFohzt5aN",
          "nombreActividad" : "Avances Transportempo",
          "tipoActividad" : "Avance",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "100000"
        },
        "-Lkeqv4z0tpWqViGlRJ5" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "31/7/2019",
          "idKey" : "-Lkeqv4z0tpWqViGlRJ5",
          "nombreActividad" : "Avance AFE2",
          "tipoActividad" : "Avance",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "800000"
        },
        "-Lkf-xUx8gi_g0GCBBIe" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "30/6/2019",
          "idKey" : "-Lkf-xUx8gi_g0GCBBIe",
          "nombreActividad" : "Avance Transportempo2",
          "tipoActividad" : "Avance",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "1500000"
        },
        "-Lkf0j_g6-EvhPy_1EMl" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "31/8/2020",
          "idKey" : "-Lkf0j_g6-EvhPy_1EMl",
        },
        "-Lkf0nifpWEpQYXcbXHm" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "30/11/2019",
          "idKey" : "-Lkf0nifpWEpQYXcbXHm",
          "nombreActividad" : "Avance AFE4",
          "tipoActividad" : "Avance",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "1200000"
        },
        "-Lkf0y73w0pGyy7UOufp" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "20/4/2019",
          "idKey" : "-Lkf0y73w0pGyy7UOufp",
          "nombreActividad" : "Avances CicloSiete2016",
          "tipoActividad" : "Avance",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "4200000"
        },
        "-Lkf1RzfEKKXbLkiHxnN" : {
          "fechaAvance" : "20/3/2019",
          "usuario" : "Andres Mora",
          "valorAvance" : "840500"
        }
      }
    }
```

Dejo el JSON para analisis...

Comment: ¿Que te devuelve `Logger.log(data)` ?

Comment: @JackNavaRow Se trata de Google Apps Script, el cual si permite que los archivos tengan caracteres unicode incluyendo acentos en los nombres de archivos.

Comment: bueno , creo que la pregunta es que nos diga cual linea de error que falla

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es esta `range.setValue(JSON.parse(data))`

Comment: :O ya comprendi!! el `JSON.parse ` convierte a Objeto, y el range.setValue espera es un valor primitivo!

Comment: Creo que el origen de el error es en esta linea :
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,4,2);

Comment: @JackNavaRow Casi,casi ya que las fechas no son primitivos :)

Comment: @AndresMora No, el origen no es `var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,4,2)`. Si gustas agrega eso a la pregunta indicando porque lo piensas y con mucho gusto edito mi respuesta para explicar porque no lo es. Por cierto, para poder darte orientación mas precisa sobre cómo solucionar el error describe el JSON que devuelve firebase.

Comment: Claro, gracias rubén ya subí el JSON aunque no creo que sean los datos del JSON

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(data)` devuelve un objeto no necesariamente un argumento válido para `setValue`. Los tipos de valores que acepta `setValue` son

1. Cadena de texto
2. Número
3. Boleano
4. Fecha (objeto tipo Date)

Ni objetos del tipo `{nombre:'Juan',apellido:'Pérez'}` ni del tipo Array son válidos como argumentos de `setValue`

Dependiendo del valor u objeto que devuelva la función `getFirebaseData` y particularmente lo que quieras agregar a la hoja de cálculo será la forma de solucionarlo.

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue